# Limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} x^y$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^y = ?$$

Can L'hopitals rule be used for for two variables?

At least according to the power rule

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x^y \implies yx^{y-1}
$$
Which amounts to $0 \cdot (0^{-1})$

Comment: As written, y is a constant. Are you also assuming $y$ is converging to zero?

Comment: @jwj11iv: isn't L'hopitals rule used for fractions only? Your limit is $0$ if $y\neq 0$

Comment: The reason why I ask is because someone explained to me that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, x^n > 0 $$ is a true statement... However I noticed a problem for x = 0. Since for example x=0,n=1 is 0, then something like (x=0,n=0 or x=0,n=-1) must be true in order for the predicate to hold true. I am trying to figure out how the above two scenarios (x=0,n=0 or x=0,n=-1) for the predicate can be greater than 0 and not be considered undefined or indeterminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to assume $\lim_{x\to0^+}$, as $x^y$ is not well defined for $x<0$. (Or the limit can only be established for rational $y$ with an odd denominator.)

For $y>0$, the limit is $0$, because for every $\delta>0$ we can find $\epsilon$ s.t. $0\le x<\delta\implies 0\le x^y<\epsilon$: take $\epsilon=\delta^y$.

For $y=0$, the limit is $1$, as for every $x>0$, $x^0=1$.

For $y<0$, the limit does not exist ($\infty$). Consider that $x^y=1/x^{-y}$.

Comment: Could you please share how each limit was found. It has been about 2 years since I did calculus.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Is it wrong to assume that the predicate statement $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, x^n > 0 $$ contains all necessary assumptions to assume that we are looking at y=0 moving towards x=0 from the left? I guess what I am asking is it inapprorpiate to assume that for x=0, y=0 and y<0 are both undefined in the context of the predicate statement.

Comment: No idea what you mean. And the "predicate statement" is false for $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me Yves :)
Is the predicate false because of the following reasoning?

In order to determine limits the function in question must be continuous. Since the domain of n is limited to the set of Integers, X^n is not a continuous function and so the function's limit values cannot be computed?

Comment: Not at all. $x^n$ is a continuous function, as is $x^y$. The predicate is false because $0^n=0$.

Comment: I am a bit confused because 0^n = 1 when n=0. Is it because  $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, x^n > 0 $$  AND $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, x^n > 0 $$ are fundamentally different predicates due to the comma?

Comment: No, $0^0$ is undefined.